# settings UI, how to untoggle

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, darkmode

I am working on a settings UI, I want to make sure that after I untoggle a certain variable, the application goes back to normal.

If I toggle the app should go to dark mode (working well), but after untoggling it should go back to light, but so far I can only set it dark, even when I untoggle nothing happens.

I have tried setting a true false, but it did not work and I couldn't toggle at all with this method

```
          onToggle: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              darkMode = value;
              if(darkMode=true)
              AdaptiveTheme.of(context).setDark();
              else
              AdaptiveTheme.of(context).setLight();
              print(darkMode);
   }
```

This did not work

Here is the code that I am using:

```
    SettingsSection(
      title: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('34_string'),
      tiles: [
        SettingsTile.switchTile(
          title: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('35_string'),
          enabled: notificatonsEnabled,
          leading: Icon(Icons.palette),
          onToggle: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              darkMode = value;
              AdaptiveTheme.of(context).setDark();
              print(darkMode);
              //theDarkMode();
            });
          },
          switchValue: darkMode,
        ),
      ]),
```

Comment: Try darkMode ?  AdaptiveTheme.of(context).setDark() : AdaptiveTheme.of(context).setLight();

Comment: My friend thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is wrong : `if(darkMode)` instead of `if(darkMode=true)`